# Can parameter be greyed out in SSRS 2005?

Tags: reporting-services

In one of my SSRS report i had a requirement asking to grey out  one parameter based up on the selection of some other parameter value. i did a work around and couldn't find anything of that sort.

Is there any other way  that i should know?

Thanks,
San

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the answer to this question:

[Updating report parameters based on parameter selection? (SSRS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053396/updating-report-parameters-based-on-perameter-selection-ssrs/1053407#1053407)