# Report Viewer Freezing When Processing

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportviewer, report-viewer2010

I am currently working on a project where remote users will have their own instance of an application (*developed in Visual Studio 2010*) and a copy of the database which is synchronised with a central database on a server; people within the office will also have access to this application, which is hosted on the server.

On each of the remote user’s laptops and on the server are reports generated in Microsoft Reporting Services and within the application I use a report viewer (*available in toolbox of Visual Studio 2010*) to view these reports.

On one of the remote user’s machines I am able to view all the reports without any issues, but when trying to view them on the server, when selecting a Parameter that depends on another parameter all parameter fields become disabled and when you click on view report button nothing happens (As shown in the picture below).

[image]
*Practice Parameter is populated depending on value selected in region parameter*

If I was to view these reports directly by going to localhost/Reports_SQLEXPRESS, these reports work as they should and there are no issues.

I have run the following [exe](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6442) on the server but with no avail.

**Information about the machines**

***Server Machine***
Operating System: Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise (Service Pack 1)

Database: SQL 2008 R2

Visual Studio Installed: No (Never been installed)

IIS Installed: 7.5.7600.16385

***Remote User Machine***
Operating System: Windows 7 Professional (Service Pack 1)

Database: SQL Express 2008 R2 with Advanced Services

Visual Studio Installed: Yes (Visual Studio 2008 & 2010)

IIS Installed: 7.5.7600.16385

Comment: I would make sure you follow the steps posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053396/updating-report-parameters-based-on-perameter-selection-ssrs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed my error was caused by a JavaScript error that was occurring on the server copy and not on the remote users computer.

The error I was getting was the following:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.ArgumentNullException: Value
>   cannot be null.
>       Parameter name: panelsCreated[2]

I found the solution on the [Codeplex](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/26725) website, it seems to be a bug when using .Net4 and the ReportViewer2010. As mentioned in the link above, I added the property ScriptMode to my AjaxToolkitScriptManager and set the property to Release Mode and it now works.

---

I have also experienced another issue where the ReportViewer freezes an displays no data in IE11.

In the Event Viewer is is throwing the following error

> Missing URL parameter: IterationId

I was able to fix this with the instructions from the following post

[SSRS Report Viewer - Report chart fails to display in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28049691/ssrs-report-viewer-report-chart-fails-to-display-in-ie11)

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure you follow the steps posted here: [Updating report parameters based on parameter selection? (SSRS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053396/updating-report-parameters-based-on-perameter-selection-ssrs)

There might be something wrong with how the referencing is working.