# What causes SSRS to use Blank.gif, breaking reports in IE11?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, internet-explorer-11, reportviewer

There have been a few questions asking about the error caused by IE 11 not loading SSRS reports...

- [SSRS Report Viewer - Report chart fails to display in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28049691/ssrs-report-viewer-report-chart-fails-to-display-in-ie11)
- [ReportViewer IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21993721/reportviewer-ie-11)

The solution seems to be to check the query string for **blank.gif** and make some changes to the URL.

Because only some of our reports are broken I'm asking a more general question, why does SSRS reference **blank.gif** sometimes and not others? Is there something I can change on the broken reports to make them work now before the website is redeployed with [the other accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22000827/251614)?