# Update a value of report parameter in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to update parameter value in ssrs report builder tool.
say if i want to update value of parameter "datetime" and select a value from drop down, i am getting a dropdown instead of textbox
. How to update a value of datetime when i change a value of another parameter ?

[image]

in the above image timeframe if change then the value should reflect in 'start' datetime field but it wont. The same works if i do it for dropdopwn i.e. startdate field if i change value in timeframe it changes in startdate but not in start datetime field.

it is different from the other post as am not trying to do a cascading drop down i am trying to update a date field with a dropdown,

Comment: Please add some images so we can understand you better.

Comment: I have updated the post and also i tried making startdate field internal or hidden and map value to start field but either way it did not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053396/updating-report-parameters-based-on-parameter-selection-ssrs Look at that question. I think that is what you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating report parameters based on parameter selection? (SSRS)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053396/updating-report-parameters-based-on-parameter-selection-ssrs)